# callback to check specific MQTT topic (not just check the payload)

Tags: arduino, mqtt, publish-subscribe

I currently use the below callback to check the PAYLOAD of incoming MQTT messages, but does anyone know how I could continue to do this but also find messages coming under a specific TOPIC?

```
void callback(char * topic, byte * payload, unsigned int length) {
    char p[length + 1];
    memcpy(p, payload, length);
    p[length] = NULL;

    if (!strcmp(p, "home")) {
        Particle.publish(DEVICE_NAME, HOME_MSSG, 60, PRIVATE);
    } else if (!strcmp(p, "chome")) {
        Particle.publish(DEVICE_NAME, CHOME_MSSG, 60, PRIVATE);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Assuming [this library](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient) `topic` will be pointing to the topic (null-terminated string) so use that to compare against your desired topics (assuming that there is more to the question than this?).

Comment: Thank you. It's actually this library https://github.com/hirotakaster/MQTT - I'm sorry but I'm a bit greener than you kindly assume. I'm not sure how I'd go about that.  :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic can be handled in pretty much the same way as the payload; e.g.

```c
if (!strcmp(topic, "thisIsATopic")) {
        // do something
}
```

Note that the payload is copied for two reasons:

- The [buffer](https://github.com/hirotakaster/MQTT/blob/master/src/MQTT.cpp#L282) is reused once the callback returns (so if you store that pointer and refer to it later it may not contain what you expect).
- The message is binary so it is important to ensure a `\0` is added to the end if using functions like `strcmp` (to avoid overruns).

It looks like the library you are using [copies the topic](https://github.com/hirotakaster/MQTT/blob/master/src/MQTT.cpp#L274) so you should be fine using that as-is (unlike with some [other libraries](https://github.com/knolleary/pubsubclient/blob/master/src/PubSubClient.cpp#L400)).